# Can you use query builder to build a query with a dynamic WHERE clause at runtime in laravel3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

I know in Laravel 4 you can create a dynamic WHERE clause at runtime as from the following question:

[Can you use query builder to build a query with a dynamic WHERE clause at runtime in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850774/can-you-use-query-builder-to-build-a-query-with-a-dynamic-where-clause-at-runtim)

But can you do the same in laravel 3?

If not, is your only option instead to create raw SQL code as in the following:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;

$first = 1;
foreach($items as $key => $val)
{
   if($first) $SQL .= " WHERE ";
       else $SQL .= " AND ";
   $SQL .= $key . " LIKE " . $VAL;
   $first = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works pretty much the exact same way.  Just use `$query = DB::table('tablename');` in place of the first line in the related post then use it as the rest of the example shows.

Comment: That's not working.  I get a `Method [all] is not defined on the Query class`

Comment: Can you provide a small working example showing how this is accomplished in Laravel 3?

Comment: @WildBill can you please show us the code that you are using that is requesting the "all" method?

Comment: As the other question suggests, I tried a `

$query = $tableModel->newQuery();

foreach($items as $key => $val) {
    $query->where($key, "LIKE", '%'.$val.'%');
}

$query->all();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using something like this:

```
$query = DB::table($table);

if(isset($key1) && isset($val1)) {
    $query->where($key1, 'LIKE', $val1);
}

if(isset($key2) && isset($va2)) {
    $query->where($key2, '=', $val2);
}

$result = $query->get(); // returns all matching models
```

You can chain as many `where` clause as you need until you call the `get()` method. Also check [this answer/L-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254909/how-to-make-laravel-query-builder-like-codeigniter-active-record/19256420#19256420) to get another idea. Reading the [Laravel - 3](http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/fluent) manual would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query builder to perform queries such as this.

```
 $query = DB::table($table);

 // Get only the fields from the form that we care about...
 $form_fields = Input::get('email', 'username');

 // Build a dynamic query based on the form with WHERE's
 foreach ($form_fields as $name=>&$value) {
      $query->where($name, '=', $value);
 }

 // Finally get all of the results...
 $results = $query->get();
```

This does work fine in Laravel 3. Check out this [[http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1494]](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1494%5d) forum post for more information